# Redrawing frame using JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

I am beginner with java; I have recently moved from another programming language and I only know basics.
I have a problem with redrawing using JPanel. I can draw text when I create new object, but I have problems redrawing it. Function tick() is called in short intervals by Main class and is supposed to redraw JPanel.

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Surface extends JPanel{
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawString("Hello World! "+Main.integer, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}
class Display extends JFrame {

    public Display() {
        Surface surface = new Surface();
        setTitle("salami");
        setSize(400, 300);
    }
    public void tick() {
        surface.redraw();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should either repaint() or revalidate() the component

Comment: @HuangChen I have solved just a part of a problem. It seems that "Surface surface = new Surface()" works in another way than previous "add(new Surface())" and it causes "Hello World!" to not draw at all. However, I can't access surface for later repainting when it is created using "add(new Surface())". How can I solve that?

Comment: I believe creating "Surface surface = new Surface()" recreates the surface without displaying it. Your display method should do what it's says it does which is "Display" rather you should just create the surface elsewhere and make it visible in Display()

Comment: What's a `Main.integer`?   For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: BTW - for the immediate problem, try changing `public Display() {
 Surface surface = new Surface();` to `Surface surface = new Surface();  public Display() {`   ;)

Comment: In addition to other comments: 1) you don't add the Surface to the frame. 2) The Surface class doesn't contain a draw(...) method. Without a proper `MCVE` or `SSCCE` we are just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you redraw the JPanel.

Here's the simplest example I have of a redrawn JPanel.  It's a clock that's redrawn every 200 milliseconds.

[image: Simple Clock GUI]

You create the GUI first, then use a Runnable in a Thread or a Swing Timer to update the GUI periodically.

And here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleClock implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel panel;

    private JTextField clockDisplay;

    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        createClockPanel();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(this);
        new Thread(timer).start();
    }

    private void createClockPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 6));

        clockDisplay = new JTextField(12);
        clockDisplay.setEditable(false);
        clockDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        panel.add(clockDisplay);
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        timer.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        clockDisplay.setText(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleClock());
    }

    public class Timer implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running;

        private SimpleClock clock;

        private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;

        public Timer(SimpleClock clock) {
            this.clock = clock;
            this.running = true;
            this.timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                displayTime();
                sleep();
            }

        }

        public void displayTime() {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            final String s = timeFormat.format(date);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clock.setText(s);
                }
            });
        }

        public void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: Alt+Print Screen will give a cropped version of the active window.  See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `extened JPanel` surface to your `JFrame`

```
public Display() {
    Surface surface = new Surface();
    add(surface);
    setTitle("salami");
    setSize(400, 300);
}
```

If this does not work post a `SSCCE`